# How drawString/text and don't zoom the text when using scale?

Tags: java, java-2d, affinetransform

Zooming on Shapes depend on mouse position is working fine, but I want to keep the font size, so drawString - text should not be zoomed in or zoomed out. It should stay with the same size and don't zoom together with the shape.

I did some tests with AffineTransform but could not find a really good solution.

Hope that somebody have an idea. Maybe I do not to see the wood for the trees :/

ScroolnZoom2D.java

```
package scroolnzoom2d;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.geom.NoninvertibleTransformException;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ScroolnZoom2D extends JFrame implements  MouseWheelListener {

    PaintCanvas painting=new PaintCanvas();

    public ScroolnZoom2D(){
        super();
        this.setTitle("Frame");
        this.setSize(500,500);

        this.getContentPane().add(this.painting,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        painting.addMouseWheelListener(this);

        //Close
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });              

        this.setVisible(true);  
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent me) {
        Point2D prePoint=getPointInBi(me.getX(),me.getY());
        Point2D afterPoint=null;

        //Zoom In/Out on wheel movement
        if (me.getUnitsToScroll() > 0) {
            painting.at.scale(0.80, 0.80);
        } else {
            painting.at.scale(1.20, 1.20);
        }

        afterPoint=getPointInBi(me.getX(),me.getY());
        painting.at.translate(afterPoint.getX()-(prePoint.getX()),(afterPoint.getY()-prePoint.getY()));
        painting.repaint();

    }

    private Point2D getPointInBi(double X,double Y){
        Point2D point2Transfer = new Point2D.Double(X,Y);
        try {
            return painting.at.inverseTransform(point2Transfer, null);
        } catch (NoninvertibleTransformException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScroolnZoom2D gui=new ScroolnZoom2D();
    }
}
```

PaintCanvas.java

```
package scroolnzoom2d;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PaintCanvas extends JPanel{

    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

    private BufferedImage bi;
    private Graphics2D g2bi;
    private int w,h;

    Font TextFont;
    int varFontSize=11; //Text Size

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);       

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        w=this.getSize().width;
        h=this.getSize().height;

        bi=new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        g2bi=bi.createGraphics();

        g2bi.transform(at);  

        //Draw Rectangle
        Rectangle r=new Rectangle(w/2,h/2,200,80);
        g2bi.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2bi.draw(r);

        //Draw Text
        TextFont = new Font("Dialog",1,varFontSize);
        g2bi.setFont(TextFont);
        g2bi.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2bi.drawString("Should stay the same text size \"11\"", w/2, h/2);

        //Draw BufferedImage
        g2.drawImage(bi,0,0, this);
    }

}
```

I was testing to change the text-size as I was zooming in or zooming out with scale. It work but not 100% :( Does anybody have some ideas?

```
    //Zoom In/Out on wheel movement
    if (me.getUnitsToScroll() > 0) {
        painting.at.scale(0.80, 0.80);
        //Zoom out
        System.out.println(painting.varFontSize);
        System.out.println(painting.at.getScaleX());
        painting.varFontSize=painting.varFontSize+4;

    } else {
        painting.at.scale(1.20, 1.20);
        painting.varFontSize=painting.varFontSize-3;
        //Zoom in

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's easy: draw the text *before* changing the transform of the Graphics, and then the text size will be unaffected.

Comment: The problem is, if I draw the text before changing the transform, the text gonna stay in the same position, but I want to keep the text size and also to change the position within the box. So for example, if I zoom in the box, the text should not be zoomed but should be stayted on the top of the box. The position should be adapted to the scale, but the text size should not be changed.

Comment: Well, then there are several solutions: 1) change the size of the font so that it compensates the scaling 2) compensate by scaling the font with Font.deriveFont(AffineTransform trans) 3) apply first a translation transform to the graphics, that moves the font into the right place (this requires some mathematical thinking), paint the text, then replace the translation with your scaling translation and paint the rest.

Comment: I tried to change the size of the font, but I could not get a good result out of it :( I added the syntax I used to change the size.

Comment: //Zoom In/Out on wheel movement
    if (me.getUnitsToScroll() > 0) {
        painting.at.scale(0.80, 0.80);
        //Zoom out
        System.out.println(painting.varFontSize);
        System.out.println(painting.at.getScaleX());
        painting.varFontSize=painting.varFontSize+4;

    } else {
        painting.at.scale(1.20, 1.20);
        painting.varFontSize=painting.varFontSize-3;
        //Zoom in

    }

Comment: I tried to solve it with the above methode, but its not working well, does anybody have a working idea, or some sugesstion what I can improve in my solution? Thank you very much